# adding blank spaces by .Net bot Framework in ms teams app

Tags: .net, microsoft-teams

how can I add blank spaces by bot framework in MS teams app?
I  have tried &nbsp; also but it is not working. I am using c# language

Should give output as

```
Low    : 1
Medium : 2
High   : 3 
Urgent : 4
```

Comment: Hey, I tried with &nbsp; for blank space and \n\n for new line . It worked fine . Can you please share code snippet?

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of the code so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is how I have done:
`await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Low&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;1\n\nMedium&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;2"), cancellationToken);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try building an adaptive card like below

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "Low",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Medium",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "High",
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Urgent",
                    "value": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Paste this in the adaptive card designer - https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ to see the output